# Size of hidden folders under mount points

Tags: linux, storage, local-storage, mount

I am trying to guess the disk used on a linux system. The problem is that with commands like 'du -kxa / |sort -g'  I see there is less space used than the filesystem reports (8Gb from a partition of 19Gb). I suspect that there are hidden files and folders under several mount points. I can't unmount the disks because is a production machine and it can't be stopped easily.

The question is:

On linux how can I get the folders and files hidden under a mount point? Is there any way to measure this space?

Linux version: Redhat enterprise linux server 5.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is one thing bind mounts are useful for. Assuming I have two separate file systems `/usr`, and `/usr/local`, you can do this to see if `/usr/local` is hiding anything:

```
mkdir /tmp/usr
mount --bind /usr /tmp/usr
ls /tmp/usr/local
# clean up if necessary
umount /tmp/usr
rmdir /tmp/usr
```

Comment: Thanks! it works!. If I do `mount --bind /mnt/ /tmp/conoc` I can see the original disk, not the mounted filesystems!

Answer (score -2):

Hidden files (whose names start with a dot) exist only for the `ls` commands and for the shell file expansion. Otherwise, they are just files whose only name starts with a dot.

Also, a file can still use space in the filesystem if it has no more names. This may happen with files still opened by some process, which [unlink(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/unlink.2.html)-ed its last name.

You could use `lsof` to find out which processes are opening some files. You could use `/proc/1234/fd` to get the open files of process 1234.

To get the hidden files under some directory, you might use

```
 find /some/dir -name '.*' -ls
```

Also, a file uses more space on the disk than needed for its data. Read more about [inode pointer structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode_pointer_structure), [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), [fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29) ... Usually, very small files (of a dozen bytes) eat two disk sectors (eg a kilobyte).

Comment: Thanks for your response. For me the command du reports also hidden files.

Comment: This response is confused about what is meant by hidden files in this context.